# Connecting to MYSQL using php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to connect to MYSQL using php, but when I use the following command:

```
$link=mysql_connect("localhost","root","password");
```

and echo $link, it gives me Resource id #98. What does this mean? Am I not connected?

Okay, I guess it sounds like the connection is okay. Now, with the following code, I am not seeing any changes in the mysql database. Why could that be?

```
<?php

$conn=new mysqli("localhost","root","password","database");

$sql="INSERT INTO chat_active (user, time) 
VALUES('John', '1234')";

?>
```

Comment: I'll be the first to say mysql_ is deprecated - use mysqli_ or pdo instead :)

Comment: The return of mysql_connect is "resource", not a string.  When you echo it, it tells you the resource ID. All looks good!  If you are having problems retrieving code let us see the rest of your code.

Comment: Since you are not returning any error then the connection to the database server has been made. The next step is to tell the database server which database that you want to use. Then you can run your queries.

Comment: *"I am not seeing any changes in the mysql database. Why could that be?"* - [Because of this...](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30419301/).

Comment: @MortimerCat sorry for the previous tag; I mistook you for the OP. *long day*.

Answer (score 2):

What makes you think you are not connected?

[According to the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php), `mysql_connect()`

> [r]eturns a MySQL link identifier on success or FALSE on failure.

Since it did not return `FALSE`, but rather a resource identifier, that means **the connection was successful**.

Also note that **the mysql extension is deprecated** since PHP 5.5.0 as MortimerCat pointed out. Instead you should look into the [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or the [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension.

Comment: The reason why I think it is not connected is because when I do something like this:

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO chat_active VALUES('user', 'time')");

nothing happens to my database.

Comment: @TylerShukert Well, this can have a thousand different reasons. The connection is most likely not one of them.

Comment: @TylerShukert post full code with errors. we are not psychici

Answer (score 1):

> *"Now, with the following code, I am not seeing any changes in the mysql database. Why could that be?"*

As per your edit which you are now using `mysqli_` to connect with, and that you're saying that you're not seeing any changes in your database, is because:

- **You're not passing the DB connection to your query** and it is required when using `mysqli_`.

Rewrite, with a few more goodies:

```
<?php
$conn=new mysqli("localhost","root","password","database");

// Check if you've any errors when trying to access DB
if ($conn->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $conn->connect_error);
    exit();
}

$sql="INSERT INTO chat_active (user, time) VALUES ('John', '1234')";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

// Check if you've any errors when trying to enter data in DB
if (!$result)
{
    throw new Exception($conn->error);
}
else{
    echo "Success";
}
```

- Read the manual http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php
- Once you've grasped that, get to know [**`mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *they're much safer*.

---

**References:**

- http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

---

**Footnotes:**

Your column names `user, time` suggests that you're trying to enter a string and what appears to be and to be intended as "time" and that the `user` column is set to `varchar`.

Make sure that you haven't setup your `time` column other than a datetime-related type, otherwise MySQL may complain about that.

- MySQL stores dates as `YYYY-mm-dd` as an example.

Visit https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html in regards to different date/time functions you can use.

**MySQL references:**

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/data-types.html
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html

Answer (score 0):

You yould use mysqli or PDO.
Here's a connection example with PDO:

```
<?php
$dbuser = 'user';
$dbpasswd = 'passwd';
$dbname = 'dbname';

try {
    $gbd = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$dbname;charset=utf8", $dbuser, $dbpasswd);
    $gbd->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }

catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```

PDO CRUD examples:

```
//INSERT
try {
    $sentence = $gbd->prepare("INSERT INTO table (param1, param2) VALUES (:param1, :param2)");
    $sentence->bindParam(':param1', $param1);
    $sentence->bindParam(':param2', $param2);
    $sentence->execute();
    }

catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Query failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }

//SELECT
try {
    $sentence = $gbd->prepare("SELECT param1,param2 FROM table WHERE param1 = :param1 AND param2 = :param2)");
    $sentence->bindParam(':param1', $param1);
    $sentence->bindParam(':param2', $param2);
    $sentence->execute();
    while ($row = $sentence->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ //Also available FETCH_NUM,FETCH_BOTH AND OTHERS
        $result['param1'] = $row['param1'];
        $result['param2'] = $row['param2'];
    }
    }
catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Query failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }

//UPDATE
try {
    $sentence = $gbd->prepare("UPDATE table SET param1 = :param1, param2 = :param2)");
    $sentence->bindParam(':param1', $param1);
    $sentence->bindParam(':param2', $param2);
    $sentence->execute();
    }

catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Query failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }

//DELETE
try {
    $sentence = $gbd->prepare("DELETE table WHERE param1 = :param1 AND param2 = :param2)");
    $sentence->bindParam(':param1', $param1);
    $sentence->bindParam(':param2', $param2);
    $sentence->execute();
    }

catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Query failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
```

And here's PDO manual
http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Answer (score 0):

u are not executing that query.u are only declaring that query.

for execution do--

$conn->query($qry);

it will,execute ur query.

Comment: Thank you for this. Is there a good tutorial website where I could learn this?

Comment: ya u can,get the tutorial at w3schools.com under php mysql.